# How to display delayed text in a simple way using js/jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to create a html5 game. The game master uses a chat-like system to communicate with the user. The chat messages should appear one after another, each with a specific delay. I named the elements using the id parameter from 1 to n and I'm just looping through the ids to display them one after another.

I want to set a custom delay for every message, without writing anything inside of the .js file I'm using. The best way would be writing it inside of the html tag, like this: `<p class="msg" id="1" delay="0">`. How can I access the value stored in delay, when I'm accessing the element with `$("#1")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a data-* attribute instead and use jquery data api, other wise you can just do `$('#1').attr('delay')` but using a data-* would be more correct.

```
<p class="msg" id="1" data-delay="0">
```

and

```
$('#1').data('delay'); //This will return 0 as a number rather than as a string which would if you access it with attr
```

You can see a major difference here **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2r2V6/)**

Comment: +1 I had the doubt why all are preferring `data-*` attributes.  But with your demo it is very clear and understood.  But this can be rectified by parsing (`parseInt($('#2').attr('delay'),10)`)right?

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan Yes Praveen. Using the data attribute you get that flexibility (apart from rectifying the issue of adding an invalid attribute `delay` to html), You don't need to access DOM (avoiding a DOM operation while doing `attr`) instead just access if from internal cache using `data` api (or `dataSet.delay` incase of vanilla JS ) and it can cast anything i.e object, array, numeric values etc without having to parse it separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **data elements**. This would mean that in your HTML tags you add `data-custom = 'value'`, and then you can access it with `$("selector").data("custom")`.

In this case it would mean that you'd have: `<p class="msg" id="1" data-delay="0">` and use it with `$("p.msg").data("delay")`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you want to use data-attributes. Rather than `delay`, use `data-delay`, like this:

```
<p data-delay="0">Text</p>
```

You can access this in jQuery in two ways, either by using `$('p').data('delay')` or `$('p').attr('data-delay')`.

Secondly, you probably don't want to use numbers as your ID. CSS can't reference IDs by values that start with numbers. If you must have an attribute that is a number, I recommend using `data-id` instead.